# Not able to connect from Google Cloud Compute Engine to Cloud SQL server

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a Cloud SQL server instance, which is the relatively new Google Cloud SQL service for the Microsoft SQL format, from a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance. The compute engine is located in the same project as the sql instance. I'm following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect) exactly. I've installed the `mssql-cli` using pip and then I execute this command as in the tutorial:

```
 ~$ gcloud sql connect sql-practice-ms --user=root
```

It then starts looking promissing:

```
    Whitelisting your IP for incoming connection for 5 minutes...done.
```

But after a minute or so, I get this error:

```
    ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) Mssql-Cli client not found.  Please install a mssql-cli client and make sure it is in PATH to be ab
    le to connect to the database instance.
    ~$
```

Comment: Hmmm...the link you provided links to an SDK reference, not a tutorial. Is that the right link?

Comment: Which operating system do you have on your VM.I would recommend you to follow official documentation for connecting to your instance [1].


Also you may check the issues with the python library you are using  [2] 
[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-overview
[2] https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-mssql-cli-new-interactive-command-line-tool-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I was able to solve this by noting that the administrative user is automatically called `sqlserver` and not `root` and by realizing that it would work best in Ubuntu and thus by using an Ubuntu machine.  When I use that then it works:

```
gcloud sql connect sql-ractice-ms --user=sqlserver -d testdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, for me the fix was to install the mssql-cli in python because Google Cloud CLI uses python:

```
pip install mssql-cli
```